# How do I update the body of a node using a query?

Tags: nodes

Let us consider I have a node called "DrupalTest" for which I need to update the body content using AJAX.

Shall I execute a query, or is there any other way to update the body content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Load the node using [node_load()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_load).
2. Set the body property of the node; examine the node object to determine which one the body property is. If you have the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module installed, [kpr()](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/kpr/6) will help you there.
3. Save the node using [node_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_save).

This ensures that the hooks associated with updating a node get executed, and that the cache is properly cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the detailed code for above answer

1. Determine the node id if possible. loan the node

   if(is_numeric($nid)){
       $node = node_load($nid);
       $node->body['und'][0]['value'] = "your body content here ";
       $node_save($node);
   }

**Saving node's fields without saving the node itself**

```
<?php
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $node->field_fieldname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'some value';
  node_save($node);
?>
```

There may be a case when you might want to save a node's field, but not the whole node itself. For example,if you may not want to update the node's timestamp for the last update, because you want it to be changed by human user activity only. In another case, you may not want to call node_save() and thus invoke chain reactions such as email notifications when the node is updated.

A Drupal function `field_attach_update()` may save your day if you encountered a similar problem that I had. You could actually replace `node_save()` with `field_attach_update()`,

```
<?php
  $node = node_load($nid);
  $node->field_fieldname[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = 'some value';
  field_attach_update('node', $node);
?>
```

The first argument takes 'entity type', which means it can be used for user, comment, etc, as well as node.

**If you want to update a single field only and save some time by skipping other fields** (because there are a lot and/or the routine is in a loop), you could remove unwanted fields first; the second argument ($node in the example) does not need to be complete with all possible fields.

by these ways you can update those node. easily ,efficiently and quickly.